# Photoshop CS6 tabs are too long

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design

Every time I work in Photoshop I use multiple tabs, but It gets annoying if I have more than 3 tabs open in the same window because the tabs display the name of the file, the zoom % and the first line of text, making the tabs too long, so if I open a 4th one, it would be automatically hidden, making it harder to drag layers around my tabs. Is there a way of disabling the tabs showing the zoom % and the first line of text in the file?

**Example:** Health Banner 1.psd **@ 61.87% (The best way to prevent…)**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no mechanism to control what information is displayed in tabs. You'll need to contact Adobe for tech support.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that maybe there's an extension out there that creates alternative tabs. --- I know one extension that kind of does this: **[DoCo](http://creativedo.co/)**. It does have thumbnails, but I wouldn't be surprised if the developer would take it into consideration to add an option to hide the thumbnail and make it more compact.

Comment: I have the same issue, it would be fantastic if we could disable the metadata from the tab name, unfortunately I have not found a way to do it yet.

Answer (score 3):

I once looked for it and I was unable to find anything that would allow me to remove the metadata from the filename in the tabs.  Only option I can recommend is adding shortcuts to the window since the default has no shortcuts applied.

You can either do it manually everytime by going to `Window -> Arrange`:

[image]

or you could go to `Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts` and navigate to Window and expand the preferences and apply your own and transition to vertical tile if it gets too long:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use Duplicate Layer command in the Layer menu... Sometimes drag and drop isn't the easiest.